# Stack trace logged on different log events

Tags: java, exception, logging, logback

I have this problem with logback... I have application in aws ecs
and when exception is logged its logged on different log events for each class from the trace. How can i fix this ?
This is my logback pattern 
**value="%d %-5p [%t] [%mdc{txid}] %c{15} %msg %ex%n"**

Comment: Can you post sample input and output vs expected output?

Comment: Does each method level catch, log and throw the exception again?

Comment: I am talking about not my custom classes. For example i want to be logged this way:
`at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
 at com.shutterfly.springboard.common.logging.SetupLoggingFilter.doFilter(SetupLoggingFilter.` Instead evry lvl is logged in splunk on separate lvl